# pandas: отбор строк с максимальным значением определенного столбца для каждого индекса

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Помогите, пожалуйста, в pandas создать сводную таблицу, содержащую для каждого индекса  значения из всех столбцов, соответствующее максимальному значению из `column1`

Пример:

Создаем датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'column1': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                   'column2': [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3],
                   'column3': [1, 2, 4, 10, 7, 5, 4]})
```

Из него надо получить:

```
         column2    column3
index         
A            2        2
B            4        10
C            3        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать, например, простой группировкой + методом idxmax:

```
res = df.loc[df.groupby(['index'])['column1'].idxmax()]
```

res:

```
  index  column1  column2  column3
1     A        2        2        2
3     B        2        4       10
6     C        3        3        4
```

можно еще явно указать нужные столбцы:

```
res = df.loc[df.groupby(['index'])['column1'].idxmax(), ["index", "column2", "column3"]]
```

res:

```
  index  column2  column3
1     A        2        2
3     B        4       10
6     C        3        4
```

Не забудьте, что в вашем примере "index" - это имя столбца, а не индекс датафрейма.

Answer (score 0):

Cортируем фрейм по `'index', 'column1'`, удаляем дубликаты строк по ключу из столбца `'index'`, оставляя последнее вхождение, потом удаляем ненужный `'column1'`

```
df = df.sort_values(['index', 'column1']).drop_duplicates('index', keep='last').drop('column1',axis=1)
```

```
  index  column2  column3
1     A        2        2
3     B        4       10
6     C        3        4
```

Примечание. Если важно сохранять порядок следования значений из столбца `'index'`, то данный вариант не годится, т.к. сортирует строки, меняя их порядок.